# Formula to return "N/A" when other cell value is "No"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I get one cell to come up with "N/A" when "No" is selected from another cell's drop down?

Answer (score 5):

If you want an actual `#N/A` error in the cell then enter the formula

`=IF(A1="No",NA(),"")`

(where A1 is the cell with the drop-down), or if you just want the text "N/A" then

`=IF(A1="No","N/A","")`